# Java Lucene English Stemmer?

Tags: java, lucene

I need help indexing and searching English text using Java Lucene over Google App Engine. The only solution I have found so far was the SnowballAnalyzer (in the contrib packages), but it only supports Lucene 3.0, and GAELucene only supports lucene 2.3.1. Just changing jars doesn't really work.

Can anyone help me index my text with an English stemmer?

Answer (score 2):

The `SnowballAnalyzer` has been with Lucene for a long time now, including 2.x versions (see [its entry](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/SnowballAnalyzer.html) in the 2.4.1 API docs).

Bizarrely, though, it doesn't come as part of the standard Lucene distribution, even if it *is* in the documentation. You'll have to hunt down a version of the contrib package that is to be used for 2.3.1.

Edit: Looks like there's a copy [here](http://gisgraphy.free.fr/mavenrepo/lucene/lucene-snowball/2.3.1/).

Answer (score 1):

The [PorterStemFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/PorterStemFilter.html) is in the lucene core.  It can be used with the [StandardAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) for english stemming.

Answer (score 0):

Various companies also *sell* more sophisticated and/or speedier alternatives to Porter Stemmers implemented in a Snowball interpreter. If you have needs in that direction, post a comment and I'll elaborate, but I don't want to get accused of unjustified advertising, so I'll leave it there for now.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been better to take the risk, and put the information out there?

Comment: Did you notice the dates on all this?

Comment: For better or worse, 10-year-old posts are often relevant. I downvoted because this is little more than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lucene-2.3.1.zip](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/java/lucene-2.3.1.zip) or its neighboring files in the Lucene archive. I am unsure, however, about the degree of customization available from GAELucene. It does not appear to be open to accept arbitrary analyzers.